# React-Router stops working when I use Redux

Tags: react-redux, react-router-v4

I am trying out redux. For some reason, when I use redux, react-router no longer works properly. When I click on the Link, the url changes, but the new component does not load. It only loads if I refresh the page.

[Router without Redux](https://codesandbox.io/s/q8jol3ypzw)

[Router and Redux](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvr57orjw)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connect(...)` wrapper function from redux produces a new component. This new component implements the `shouldComponentUpdate` function to only update itself and children, when it's props are different (pr `shallowEqual`).

See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration

The standard workaround is to wrap `connect(...)` with `withRouter`. This injects new props, that forces the `connect`-ed component to update on location changes.

ie. `withRouter(connect(...))`

https://codesandbox.io/s/2xl5pp1l4n